# Sort Map in reverse order in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

When I want to sort a `Map` I use :

```
map.toSortedMap()
```

But how can I sort a map in the reverse order?

For example my `Map<Double, Int>` is sorted with `.toSortedMap()`, so I have :

```
{0.01=10, 0.05=7, 0.1=8, 0.25=6, 0.5=15, 1.0=3, 2.0=9, 5.0=8, 10.0=14, 20.0=6, 50.0=10}
```

I would like something like:

```
{50.0=10, 20.0=6, 10.0=14, 5.0=8, 2.0=9, 1.0=3, 0.5=15, 0.25=6, 0.1=8, 0.05=7, 0.01=10}
```

Comment: Try `toSortedMap(Comparator.reverseOrder​())`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As @Venkata Raju said in the comment, you can use [`java.util.Comparator.reverseOrder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reverseOrder) for this (available since 1.8):

```
map.toSortedMap(Comparator.reverseOrder())
```

You can also use the [`reverseOrder()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/reverse-order.html) function from the Kotlin standard library's [`kotlin.comparisons`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/index.html) package:

```
map.toSortedMap(reverseOrder())
```

Answer (score 4):

It is a bit late but hope this help.

for API <= 23

```
map.asIterable().reversed()
```

for API > 24

```
map.toSortedMap(Comparator.reverseOrder())
```

Comment: watch out, asIterable().reversed() returns a List and not a Map anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Comparator.reverseOrder() works above the API level 21 ... 
the easiest way to get the keys from the sortedHashmap and reverse the keys list and then get values accordingly.

```
lateinit var entries: List<String>
entries = sortedList.keys.toList<String>()
entries = entries.reversed()
//get your values from map on the basis of keys
```